# Theorem 4.14 Rudin Functional analysis (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b)

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-spaces, duality-theorems

Statement

> If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach Spaces ad if $T \in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$, then each one of the following three conditions implies the other two:

> (a) $\mathcal{R}(T)$ is closed in $Y$ $\iff$ (b) $\mathcal{R}(T^*)$ is weak*-closed in $X^*$ $\iff$ (c) $\mathcal{R}(T^*)$ is norm-closed in $X^*$.

Reporting the proof and the bits I don't understand

> PROOF: Suppose (a) holds. By Theorem 4.12 and (b) of Theorem 4.7, $\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}$ is the weak*-closure of $\mathcal{R}(T^*)$. To prove (b) it is therefore enough to show that $\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp} \subset \mathcal{R}(T^*)$. Pick $x^* \in \mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}$. Define the linear functional $\Lambda$ on $\mathcal{R}(T^*)$ by
> $$
> \Lambda T x = \left\langle x, x^*\right\rangle \;\; (x \in X)
> $$
> Note that $\Lambda$ is well defined, for if $Tx = Tx'$, then $x - x' \in \mathcal{N}(T)$; hence
> $$
> \left\langle x - x', x^* \right\rangle = 0
> $$

**Question** : To me showing that $\Lambda$ is well defined means to show that for each $y \in \mathcal{R}(T)$ then $\Lambda y$ is uniquely defined and linear. Linearity is easy enough so I skip and I guess Rudin did as well, uniquely defined I think is what the author is going for, right? Indeed if $y \in \mathcal{R}(T)$ and $Tx = y, Tx' = y$ we have the conclusion already given, namely
$$
\left\langle x - x' , x^*\right\rangle = 0
$$
but more specifically this implies
$$
0 = \left\langle x - x' , x^*\right\rangle = \left\langle x , x^* \right\rangle - \left\langle x' , x^* \right\rangle \iff \left\langle x , x^* \right\rangle = \left\langle x' , x^* \right\rangle \iff \Lambda T x = \Lambda T x'
$$
which is I guess the wanted conclusion.
Am I right?

> The open mapping theorem applies to
> $$
> T : X \to \mathbb{R}(T)
> $$
> since $\mathbb{R}(T)$ is assumed to be a closed subspace of the complete space $Y$ and is therefore complete. It follows that there exists $K < \infty$ such that to each $y \in \mathcal{R}(T)$ corresponds an $x \in X$ with $Tx = y$ and $\left\lVert x \right\rVert \leq K \left\lVert y \right\rVert$,

**Question** I don't get how the bound

$$
\left\lVert x \right\rVert \leq K \left\lVert y \right\rVert
$$

follows from the application of the open mapping theorem, can you clarify?

> and
> $$
> \left| \Lambda y \right| = \left| \Lambda T x \right| = \left| \left\langle x, x^* \right\rangle \right| \leq K \left\lVert y \right\rVert \left\lVert x^* \right\rVert
> $$
> Thus $\Lambda$ is continuous. By the Hahn-Banach Theorem, some $y^* \in Y^*$ extends $\Lambda$. Hence
> $$
> \left\langle Tx, y^* \right\rangle = \Lambda T x = \left\langle x, x^* \right\rangle
> $$
> This implies $x^* = T^* y^*$. Since $x^*$ was an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp}$, we have shown that $\mathcal{N}(T)^{\perp} \subset \mathcal{R}(T)$. Thus (b) follows from (a).

I think the remaining is straightforward, but in case I'll ask a separate question.

Comment: Hi, the open mapping theorem is used to show boundedness of the inverse map $T^{-1}$. So the bound you have is just the definition of the linear map $T^{-1}$ being bounded.

Comment: How can he show $T$ has inverse however?

Comment: The open mapping theorem says there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $T(B_X) \supset \delta \cdot B_Y$ (where $B_{Z}$ is the closed unit ball in $Z$). Thus for every $y \neq 0$ there is an $x_0 \in B_X$ with $T(x_0) = \frac{\delta}{\lVert y\rVert} \cdot y$. Take $x = \frac{\lVert y\rVert}{\delta}\cdot x_0$. It follows that $K = 1/\delta$ works.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. I think your statement is a special version of the statement given in chapter 2.