# Theorem 4.14 Rudin's Function - (c) $\Rightarrow$ (a)

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I guess a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816458/theorem-4-14-rudin-functional-analysis-a-rightarrow-b). I'm trying to work out the details of

> (c) $\mathcal{R}(T^*)$ is norm-closed in $X^*$ $\Rightarrow$ (a) $\mathcal{R}(T)$ is closed in $Y$.

Proof and questions in the middle

> Suppose next that (c) holds. Let $Z$ be the closure of $\mathcal{R}(T)$ in $Y$. Define $S \in \mathcal{B}(X,Z)$ by setting $Sx = Tx$. Since $\mathcal{R}(S)$ is dense in $Z$, Corollaryb (b) to Theorem 4.12 implies
> $$
> S^* : Z^* \to X^*
> $$
> is one-to-one.
> If $z^* \in Z^*$, the Hahn-Banach theorem furnishes an extension $y^*$ of $z^*$; for every $x \in X$.
> $$
> \left\langle x, T^* y^* \right\rangle = \left\langle T x, y^* \right\rangle = \left\langle Sx, z^* \right\rangle = \left\langle x, S^* z^* \right\rangle
> $$
> Hence $S^* z^* = T^* y^*$. It follows that $S^*$ and $T^*$ have identical ranges.

**Question 1** : Since $z^* \in Z^*$ Is $y^*$ (the extension) defined in $Y$, so $y^* \in Y^*$?

**Question 2** : I don't really understand how the equalities above show that $\mathcal{R}(S^*) = \mathcal{R}(T^*)$. To me what we should show is that for each $z^* \exists y^* : S^*z^* = T* y^*$ and such a $y^*$ is constructed using the Hahn Banach theorem, but we should also show the other way around, namely for each $y^* \exists z^* : S^*z^* = T^* y^*$. And to me the chain of equalities show the former but not the latter.

> Since (c) is assumed to hold, $\mathcal{R}(S^*)$ is closed, hence complete.

**Question 3**: Why is $\mathcal{R}(S^*)$ complete?

> Apply the open mapping theorem to
> $$
> S^* : Z^* \to \mathcal{R}(S^*)
> $$
> Since $S^*$ is one-to-one, the conclusion is that there is a constant $c > 0$ which satisfies
> $$
> c \left\lVert z^* \right\rVert = \left\lVert S^* z^* \right\rVert
> $$
> for every $z^* \in Z^*$. Hence $S : X \to Z$ is an open mapping by theorem 4.13.

**Question 4** : Not really sure how such theorem is applied, i think one of the consequences of that theorem implies open mapping but not sure which one.

> In particular $S(X) = Z$. But $\mathcal{R}(T) = \mathcal{R}(S)$, by the definition of $S$. Thus $\mathcal{R}(T) = Z$, a closed subspace of $Y$.
> This completes the proof that (c) implies (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Yes it is. $z^*$ is a linear functional defined on a subspace of $Y$ and, since the Hahn Banach hypoteses are met, it admits an extension $y^*\in Y^*$.

Question 2: You are right. But, as Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out, you can consider that for every $\tilde{y}^*\in Y^*$ then $\tilde{y}_{|Z}^*$ is an element of $Z^*$ that admits trivially $\tilde{y}^*$ as extension to the whole $Y$. Using $z^*=\tilde{y}_{|Z}^*, y^*=\tilde{y}^*$ in that chain of equalities allows you to conclude the remaining inclusion to prove.

Question 3: A closed subspace of a Banach space is complete. Since $X^*$ is Banach, this is a direct consequence of hypotesis $(c)$ and the equality $\mathcal{R}(S^*)=\mathcal{R}(T^*)$

Question 4: Observe first that the hypoteses of the open mapping theorem are satisfied by $S^* : Z^* \to \mathcal{R}(S^*)$. This theorem tells us that the mapping $S^* : Z^* \to \mathcal{R}(S^*)$ is an open mapping. But $S^* : Z^* \to \mathcal{R}(S^*)$ is also continuous, surjective and one-to-one. Now, a map which is an open continuous bijection is a homeomorphism. This means that the inverse of $S^* : Z^* \to \mathcal{R}(S^*)$ is continuous, which means it is bounded. So there exists a constant $K>0$ for which:
$$ \left\lVert z^* \right\rVert \leq K \left\lVert S^* z^* \right\rVert \qquad \forall z^* \in Z^*$$
You can now apply theorem 4.13.

Comment: Accepting your answer because it was elaborate enough for me to understand the issue. You haven't answered question 4 however.

Comment: I have just answered it as well. Thanks anyway :) (let me know if you need more details)

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1, YES.

For Question 2 given $y^{*} \in Y^{*}$ take $z^{*}$ to be the restriction of $y^{*}$ to $Z$. The chain of equalities is still valid.

Comment: How do you guarantee that $y^*$ restricted to $Z$ actually gives you one of the function you're trying to extent?